# Keeping of changes from one file inside two different changelists with Git and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I'm using Git as VCS and IntelliJ IDEA as IDE.

I want to keep my local changes (those, which I won't to commit) in the changelist with the name 'local' and other changes (intended to be committed) in my default changelist. The problem occurs when I have local changes and changes that I intend to commit in the same file. In this case, before performing the commit, I need to review all changes in those files and discard all local changes.

Is there any way to keep one part of changes in a file in the first changelist and the other part in the second changelist?

Comment: I don't think there is. Sorry. What I typically do is keep a copy of the changes for that file needed only locally in a file called something like `configuration.MINE.xml` so that I can track the difference between the three states (HEAD vs. local vs. intended change to commit)

Comment: Okay, i got it. Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: I thought that's what changelists are for. I usually use a git stash with the local changes. Commit only the changes that can be pushed, then apply the local code stash when I want to test it out locally. The annoying part is indeed when the local changes and pushable changes are in the same file. I have the pushable changes in the staged area in git, the local ones are untracked. git stash but keep staged area (checkbox in sourcetree), apply local stash, test, git reset(make sure there's nothing new), and apply the pushable stash

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, this IS possible now with IntelliJ's new support for Git's partial commits in 2018.1. You've probably already ran in to it by now, but there are two ways (at least) to have different changes in the same file exist in different change sets.

The important thing to note in any case, is that changes that sit in an unrelated, or inactive change set, will appear with a very faint color, instead of the normal green/blue/etc highlighting when viewing a dif. The faint highlighting means that is IS a change to your working copy, but not staged with 'this' change set. (might be using the wrong nomenclature here)

The two ways to keep local changes, but continue to work on things as usual follow:

1. Simply keep existing changes to a file sitting in an inactive change set, and make further modifications to the file. The default behavior is to add any new changes to the active change set. When you go to commit this file from the active change set, the inactive changes will not be included.
2. If you need to split up existing changes to two different change sets, the way I have found to do this is mildly more tedious. Hopefully someone else knows of an even better way... The way I have done it is to shelve the changes without reverting them, move the changes to an inactive change set, and revert or manually remove the changes you want to be in the active changeset. At that point, just unshelve the changes and apply them either to the active changeset, or do not apply them to a specific change set. I'm sure this can be done in reverse order (as in, keep the file active, revert the 'inactive' changes you want to keep, then unshelve the changes to the inactive change set), or any other mix and mash.

Hopefully this helps, if you haven't already figured it out!

Comment: Wow! Great, thanks a lot. I was unaware about this new feature. I still use 2017.3. Now I really want to update it to 2018. BTW, regarding your second option: seems like you can include code chunks into a commit using the checkboxes in the Diff pane of the Commit Changes dialog. Read [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more).

Comment: Seems like you also can move code chunks between changelists using the Move to another changelist action which is available from the context menu of the Diff pane in the Commit Changes dialog.